# How to display free marker list elements in 2d array

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

I am new to freemarker template. can someone please help me out here.

I am getting products list from Spring controller and I want to display 4 products in each row. I am using div rather than table. Any help is appreciated.

Below code is displaying one element in each row.

```
<div class="container">
  <#list products as product>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
              <div class="popular-products-slides owl-carousel">
                  <!-- Single Product section item starts here -->
                  <div class="single-product-wrapper">
                      <!-- Product Image -->
                      <div class="product-img">
                          <img src="${product.frontImageURL}" alt="" style="width: 200px; height: 400px;">
                          <!-- Hover Thumb -->
                          <img class="hover-img" src="${product.backImageURL}" alt="" style="width: 200px; height: 400px;">
                      </div>
                      <!-- Product Description -->
                      <div class="hover-content">
                          <div class="product-description">
                              <a href="${product.hyperLink}" target="_blank">
                                  <h4>${product.productName}</h4>
                              </a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- single product section item ends here-->
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </#list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `?chunk` then. Quoting example from https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_chunk:

```
<#assign seq = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']>

<#list seq?chunk(4) as row>
  <#list row as cell>${cell} </#list>
</#list>

<#list seq?chunk(4, '-') as row>
  <#list row as cell>${cell} </#list>
</#list>
```

Output:

```
  a b c d
  e f g h
  i j

  a b c d
  e f g h
  i j - -
```

Comment: So In may case I am using list rather than array.  Should I able to assign seq= products list?

Comment: Arrays and `List`-s are no different in FreeMarker, and the assignment is irrelevant. I only added that assignment so that my example is complete (like you can run it on https://try.freemarker.apache.org as is).

Answer (score 0):

Surrond your div with [#list](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html)

```
 <#list products as product>
  // your div
  </#list>
```

> and to list the key-value pairs of a hash (since 2.3.25):
>
> ```
> <#list hash as key, value>
> Part repeated for each key-value pair
>  </#list>
> ```